# Как удалить три символа, стоящие перед курсором?

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.div6Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  Z_ = '<div>';
  X_ = '</div>';
var
  tmp, stroka: String;
  x, y: integer;
  pt: TPoint;
begin
  tmp := Memo1.Text;
  x := Memo1.SelStart;
  if (x >= 3) then begin
      y := 3;
      x := x - 2;
  end
  else begin
      y := x;
      x := 0;
  end;
  Delete(tmp, x, y);
  Memo1.Text := tmp;

  x := Memo1.SelStart;
  y := Memo1.SelLength;
  insert(Z_, tmp, x + 1);
  insert(X_, tmp, x + Length(Z_) + y + 1);
  Memo1.Text := tmp;

  Memo1.SelStart:=x+y+5;
end;
```

Comment: @hkpp: Я что-то не понимаю смысл кода `Delete(tmp,pt.X,3);`.

Comment: @VladD Глупо, да... исправил. Теперь ничего не удаляется, просто добавляется "<div></div>"

Comment: @hkpp: А как код выглядит теперь? У вас в вопросе до сих пор `Delete(tmp,pt.X,3);`.

Comment: @VladD Ой, мозг офф. Я не знаю.

Comment: @VladD Подскажите, пожалуйста, я не знаю, что тут можно сделать. Голова болит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
tmp := Memo1.Text;

x := Memo1.SelStart;
if (x >= 3) then begin
    y := 3;
    x := x - 3;
end
else begin
    y := x;
    x : = 0;
end;

Delete(tmp, x, y);
Memo1.Text := tmp;
```

Comment: Итс воркс! Бат, символы, идущие до тех трех, которые удаляются, перебрасываются в правую часть добавленного <div></div>. Как все оставить на своих местах? Если убрать memo1.text:=tmp; в конце, тогда символы из правой части строки, идущие после добавленного <div></div>. перебрасываются в левую часть. Спасибо!

Comment: @hkpp А как вы вставляете? Покажите код.

Comment: @hkpp: Уберите первый `Memo1.Text := tmp;`, должно помочь, по идее.

Comment: @VladD Я имел в виду если убрать memo1.text:=tmp; в конце Вашего кода, тогда все символы, идущие с правой части строки, перебрасываются в левую. Моя вина. А так, оно все в левую часть строки, а в правой <div></div> остается. Причина тому - каретка, смещающаяся влево! Собственно тут и вопрос: как её вернуть?

Comment: О Боги, я наконец-то счастлив! После первого {Memo1.Text := tmp;} добавил {Memo1.SelStart:=x-1;}. Спасибо большущее Вам за помощь!

Comment: @hkpp: Отлично! Рад, что смог помочь!

Answer (score 1):

> Delete(stroka,1,3);

Delete ( в какой строке, с какого символа, сколько символов)